# Old horror/scifi/monster movie with a Bigfoot-sized monster that has red vision and attacks a woman through the floorboards

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I was very little when I saw this horrifying at the time movie, so take what i describe with a grain of salt. I saw it between 1997-1999 on VHS but I believe the movie could be anywhere between the 70s and 1996. The events took place somewhere remote, far from big buildings, population and skyscrapers. A setting very similar to the movie *Demonwarp (1988)*.

What I remember is a Bigfoot-sized monster, possibly hairy, coming out of the floor by breaking through the wooden floorboard, possibly in a cabin of sorts. The monster broke through behind an unaware woman who was sitting on a sofa or couch and hugged around her before dragging her down. That happened unexpectedly and i believe during the daylight with other people close by.

The monster had a red vision that was spying people with (it was seeing Crimson red), a bit similar to the Predator without the heat detection but more like the *Night of the Demon* (1980) creature and *Pumpkinhead 2*.

In addition a very ominous, diabolical theme was playing when the creature was stalking humans, which left a big impression on me and is one of the main reasons i want to find this movie.

I was under the impression that this monster came from space but i could be totally wrong about that.

After some debate a small group of people went to hunt it down in its underground lair that looked like a cave but had a hellish feel to it with possibly human skulls and lava.

I have searched many years for this movie and I can't find it. I've looked at all the horror movies of the 80s in the wiki. It's not a well known cult classic movie that's for sure.

Comment: I immediately thought of the craptacular _[C.H.U.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.H.U.D.)_ but its underground action is in the New York sewers and subways.

Comment: No that's not it. I updated my description with more details.

Comment: Is it possibly 'The Legend of Bogey Creek' (1972)...?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WatkxAxBsBk

Comment: Upvote for 'craptacular'

Comment: Well does it have anything of what i talked about other than the Yeti? There are a lot of bigfoot movies and i went through them all. The monster is probably something else. Closest thing i've seen to what i am looking for is the movie Demonwarp.

Comment: I've seen a few references to people seeking a film involving a devil or demon bursting through the floorboards, maybe at a farm named "Carter Place", https://horrornews.net/15324/list-top-10-devil-themed-movies/#comment-200346

Comment: Perhaps the 1988 movie "Watchers"? It had a man-sized baboon thing that would evoke thoughts of Bigfoot. I don't remember red vision, but it was after a dog that lived with a family in their house surrounded by woods.

Comment: That is watchers 1 isn't it? I have seen that movie. Actually Watchers 2 1990 is closer to what i am seeking since the monster has a vision of sorts. These movies however are too modern for the setting i remember. The movie in question had an early to mid 80s feel to it with no advanced tech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Grim" (1995)?**

This one has a bigfoot type monster who bursts up through the floorboards and lives in underground caverns that are littered with the remains of its victims. I have never seen this one and it seems to be hard to find, but I did find a trailer on YouTube and it shows many of the things you described. Here it is:

Comment: Reviews at https://www.gbhbl.com/horror-movie-review-grim-1995/ and https://www.wickedhorror.com/horror-news/cult-corner-grim-1995/

Comment: You sir might be a legend. This looks 95% to be it. I'll have to see it and get back to you.

Comment: Oh my god, oh my god, oh my god! This is really it!! Thank you so much! You are indeed a legend! You weren't kidding when you said it was hard to find. I had to make an amazon account just for that. I would never would have found this movie if it weren't for you. It isn't even listed in the wikipedia in which i spent countless hours searching plus the movie looks so old i was convinced i was wasting time looking after 1992.

Comment: Wow - that looks like something from Full Moon or Troma... naturally, I have to watch it now.